# Array view not working on Laravel Blade Template. (Undefined variable: )

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I get the counts of 3 different tables with 3 different SQL queries.

Here :

```
$Count['FirstRecords']= DB::table('table1')->where('Id',$slug)->count('Id');
$Count['SecondRecords']= DB::table('table2')->where('Id',$slug)->count('Id');
```

There aren't any problems when I check the content on controller with print_r function. I get an output like the following:

```
Array
(
    [FirstRecords] => 178
    [SecondRecords] => 302
)
```

Then I sent this array to the blade template via view function.

```
return view('View/CountView',['Records' => $Count]);
```

I'm trying to print on the blade like this:

```
{{$Records->FirstRecords}}
```

I get the following error every time when I trying to print this array on the blade template.

**Undefined variable: Records (View: {Path}**

Comment: Make sure that you are calling $Records in correct file

Comment: And second is $Records is an array not an object use it like $Records['FirstRecords']

Comment: @AbdulMoiz 

I also tried sending it via the controller as follows. As a result, I got the same error again.


`return view('View/CountView',['Records' => $Count['FirstRecords']]);`

Comment: Did you create in the view folder another view folder? Normally you just write the name of the blade. If you want to use a subfolder you would use a point instead of a slash. Here is the link to the documentation, where it is explained really well: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views

Comment: Then pass it like `return view(view.countview, compact('Count'))` and use `$FirstRecords`

Comment: @Philip I didn't happen any problem with to path structure.  Also, it's working when I send another variable without touching the path structure.

Comment: How is your blade looking like? Can you share a bit more code please?

Comment: Share controller function and blade code to understand better

Comment: @AbdulMoiz

`public function get($slug)
{
    $Count['FirstRecords']= DB::table('table1')->where('Id',$slug)->count('Id');
    $Count['SecondRecords']= DB::table('table2')->where('Id',$slug)->count('Id');
    return view('View/CountView',['Records' => $Count]);


    

}`